# The total height of the texts & circle is different (should be equal) in two drawing scenarios

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, text, height

I have the two following drawing scenarios.

Developed in Flutter Dart.

The Code is following

1. The `bool displayButtons` select one of the scenarios
2. The `double heightFactor` calculate the heights depending on mobile screen height

```dart
!displayButtons ? SizedBox(height: heightFactor*42.0):SizedBox(height: heightFactor*19.0),

!displayButtons ? SizedBox(child:CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth:5, valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Color(0xffD10274)),),height: 100.0*heightFactor,width: 100.0*heightFactor,):
          Text("Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", style:GoogleFonts.heebo(color:Color(0xff333333),textStyle:TextStyle(height:24/16,fontStyle:FontStyle.normal,fontWeight:FontWeight.w300, fontSize:16*heightFactor)),textAlign:TextAlign.center ),

!displayButtons ? SizedBox(height: heightFactor*42.0): SizedBox(height: heightFactor*(117.0)),
        Text("By", style:GoogleFonts.heebo(color:Color(0xff333333),textStyle:TextStyle(height:20/14,fontStyle:FontStyle.normal, fontWeight:FontWeight.w300, fontSize:14*heightFactor))),
```

> The total height in the first scenarios `displayButtons=false` should be `heightFactor*(42+100+42+14*14*20/14) = 204 *heightFactor`

> The total height in the second scenarios `displayButtons=true` should be `heightFactor*(19+2*16*24/16+117+14*20/14) = 204 *heightFactor`

The results are :

> In Android the heights of the two scenarios are the same

> In IOS the second scenario `displayButtons=true` is longer about `20pxl`

Any idea?

Comment: Widgets may have default padding or margin.

Comment: The Height of a line defined the the following property and I defined all of them.
And its working OK in Android
 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html

Comment: as a workaround 

If its alwasy 20 pxl long in iOS, check platform and minus 20 pxl,

bool isIOS = Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS;

Comment: also what will be heightFactor value?